# new node produced when updating children's values

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am making an Instagram-like app with Firebase and I am having difficulties getting the profile setup activity performing as I wanted it to. The Json tree looks like this

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "1" : {
      "image" : "http://something.com/something",
      "name" : "person 1"
    },
    "2" : {
      "image" : "http://someone.com/someone",
      "name" : "person 2"
    },
    "d5nDSA5QyKU7j5XWMedYZVXTqBA2" : {
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/parkir-ngasal.appspot.com/o/Profile_images%2Fcropped-1156087565.jpg?alt=media&token=28549773-a95d-4105-9287-e4e7e454113e",
      "name" : "Erik Adiguno"
    }
  },
  "posts" : {
    "post 1" : {
      "content" : "test content 1",
      "dPicture" : "http://something.com/something",
      "picture" : "http://postimage.com/postimage",
      "title" : "test title 1",
      "uid" : 1,
      "username" : "person 1"
    },
    "post 2" : {
      "content" : "test content 2",
      "dPicture" : "http://someone.com/someone",
      "picture" : "http://postimage2.com/postimage2",
      "title" : "test title 2",
      "uid" : 2,
      "username" : "person 2"
    }
  }
}
```

So the profile setup activity simply identify the currently logged on user and push() values to both the "image" and "name" child... But as you may already have guessed, it (of course) does not update the "username" and "dPicture" child from the "posts" node. Please see the code below

```
 private void startSetUpAccount() {
                final String name = mNameField.getText().toString().trim();
                final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && mImageUri !=null) {
                    mProgress.setMessage("Almost There...");
                    mProgress.show();
                    mProgress.setCancelable(false);
                    mProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    StorageReference filepath = mStorageImage.child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
                    filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            final String downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                            //data creation
                            mDatabaseUsers.child(user_id).child("name").setValue(name);
                            mDatabaseUsers.child(user_id).child("image").setValue(downloadUri);

                            mProgress.dismiss();

                            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Successfully updated username and profile picture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            mainActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(mainActivityIntent);

                        }
                    });
                }

    }
```

I have attempted 2 ways to my disappointment:

1. I tried querying ordering by "uid" child equals to the currently logged on user's id... then I got stuck because I could not get reference to the child
2. I tried getting the "name" and "dPicture" to retrieve value from the "Users" node instead of the "posts" node, but you can't put two nodes inside a recyclerview adapter right?

I am basically stuck and any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please share the [minimal code that reproduces this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for helping me out. Ok I've edited as per the your comment. Sorry hehe I am still very new with stackoverflow and Firebase

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen After more research today, I think it's wiser to go with getting the values from two different nodes Right? the name and display image from the "Users" node and the posted material (Title, Picture, and Description) from the "posts" node. Therefore everytime the update profile activity is executed, it only needs to update one node rather than all the nodes which are that user's posts... But is it possible to get values from a different database reference in one cardview?